# How to show the recording's length and the download option immediately after the recording is stopped?

Tags: javascript, stream, blob, mediastream

I'm using the program in the following demo for a personal project.
https://mdn.github.io/web-dictaphone/
(more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API)

However, every time I make a recording, the length doesn't show immediately. Nor does the download option (the three-dot thing on the right).
[the recording shown before I played it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrhsp.png)

I have to literally play the recording in order to make it show the recording duration and the download option.
[the recording shown after I played it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mAnq.png)

Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Avoid posting external links(other than jsfiddle, codesandbox or like so). Determine the part of your code that is causing the issue, then post it here

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV
Hi, thanks for your feedback.
No code in the demo (which I didn't write) is causing any issue.
The demo works fine as its sole purpose is just to demonstrate how to record audio files using MediaStream's recording API.
However, I'd like to build on this demo and need the recordings to show their durations and options to download immediately after they are added to the frontend. I don't know how to make this happen and am hoping that I can find some clue here.